# Cannot SSH Into EC2 Instance With Different Computer: Connection Refused using Putty

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, redhat, putty

I have been having trouble trying to SSH into my Red Hat Linux instance on Amazon EC2 from my home computer. I initially set it up on my work computer where I followed the steps to generate a key/pair. I am able to SSH into the server from my work computer but I am unable to SSH into the server from my home computer. When I try connecting via Putty from my home computer, it says "Connection Refused."

- I have allowed any IP address to SSH into the server.
- I have brought in my .ppk file from my work computer to my home computer and imported it into Putty. It still does not work.
- I generated a new key/pair for my home computer via Amazon web interface, imported the .ppk into my Putty on my home computer but I am still getting "Connection Refused."

At this point, I'm not sure what it can be. I'm new to working with Linux and I am assuming that if I were to mimic everything on my work computer's Putty session to my home computer it should work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried SSHing into other servers from your home machine ? Sometimes its an ISP issue that blocks SSH traffic. Are you having problems with SSHing EC2 only ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am able to SSH into web hosting servers from my home machine. When I bring my work computer home, I am still able to SSH into everything.

Comment: Also, make sure the SSH daemon is running on your server. Plus do you have a firewall on your system ? ... You can close it temporarily to check if that is the problem

Comment: The SSH daemon is running. I turned off my firewall and tested it that way and it is not working either.

Comment: Putty also throws the error "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic)"

Comment: Here is a guide from Amazon to make things work with Putty

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

I suspect its the key format issue but you can follow those steps if you have missed something out.

Comment: So are you getting *"Connection Refused."* or *"Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic)"*? There are two completely different errors, indicating completely different issues.

Comment: Anyway, please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, whoever it was. Question is pretty clear and I did my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. For some reason it was unable to resolve to the DNS. I connected directly to the public IP.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you did that?